# Redirect Standard and Error Output to Append a file, and email truncated results

Tags: cron, logs, io-redirection, email

I have a crontab that looks something like this:

```
 0 8 * * * command >> mylog.log 2>&1
```

This appends both errors and standard output into mylog.log.

In addition to what's above, I want to be able to capture only the most recent outputs of `command` and send them to my email via:

```
 mail -s 'test' myemail@domain.com
```

In other words, write all outputs to a log, and send only new outputs to an email.

I read up on tee, and something tells me that may be an answer but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 1):

After checking with a colleague, the solution ended up being incredibly simple. Just divide out the script into multiple parts. Put these parts into a shell script.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # write truncated log to temp.log 
 command > temp.log 2>&1
 # mail contents of truncated log
 mail -s 'test' myemail@domain.com < temp.log
 # append contents of truncated log to your primary log
 cat temp.log >> mylog.log
```

Then take the bash script and run it in crontab

```
 0 8 * * * bash mysh.sh
```